# Wishful thinking in Clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme, lisp

In Scheme I was used to do something like this

```
(define (f x) (g x))
(define (g x) (+ x 42))
(g 0)
```

That is, I was used to define functions in terms of other momentaneously unbounded functions.
Why isn't this possible in Clojure?  For example on a Clojure REPL the following isn't valid

```
(defn f [x] (g x))
(defn g [x] (+ x 42))
(g 0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the thing is every line is being compiled in repl, so there is no `g` function when `f` is being compiled. You should add `(declare g)` before `(defn f...` so the compiler would be aware of this function:

```
user> (declare g)
#'user/g

user> (defn f [x] (g x))
#'user/f

user> (defn g [x] (+ x 42))
#'user/g

user> (g 0)
42
```

Comment: Why doesn't the REPL automatically "declare" undefined functions? Wouldn't it be easier?

Comment: @Matteo Rich Hickey gives the rationale for this behavior in [this HN comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467809), which basically comes down to what type of error would you like to have for undefined symbols: runtime or compile time?  Common Lisp chooses runtime error, Clojure chooses compile time error.

Comment: @CurtisSummers: Common Lisp chooses: compile-time warnings, late binding and runtime errors.

Comment: CF Matthew Flatt, "The top level is hopeless." best ref I can find: http://calculist.blogspot.com/2009/01/fexprs-in-scheme.html